# Counting parent objects using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm fairly new to using linq expressions and trying to refactor some old code. Is there a way to turn the following method into a short and clean Linq expression?

```
public int GetParentCount(object o)
{ 
    int count = 0;
    object parent = GetParentObject(o);
    while (parent != null)
    {
        count++;
        parent = GetParentObject(parent);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I've tried searching but got no satisfying results

Comment: Why would you want to do this with LINQ?

Comment: Can you post structure of the objects involved? Also, what does `GetParentObject` actually do - how does it get the parent?

Comment: I see no recursion...

Comment: @Killercam I was just wondering if it's possible and if so, how to achieve this

Comment: @Floremin It's quite a complicated method that sorts it out using a conditional tree structure

Comment: @MatthewWatson You are right, I'll change the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the ancestors like so:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> AncestorsOf(MyClass obj)
{
   var parent = GetParentObject(obj);
   if (parent != null)
   { 
       yield return parent;
       foreach(var grandparent in AncestorsOf(parent))
          yield return grandparent;
   }
}
```

Getting the total count would then be a simple `AncestorsOf(obj).Count()`

Comment: FYI this isn't technically LINQ, it's just an iterator block.  It's a method that plays nice with LINQ, but it itself is not LINQ.  The refactor to make it recursive is also not helpful.  It makes it a lot less efficient.  If you kept the same iterative approach the OP used it could do the same thing much more efficiently.

Comment: Correct, the only bit that "is Linq" is the Count(). Linq is basically only operations on collections, so you need to create something that is IEnumerable/IQueryable. I don't think you can convert the recursion into an enumerable short of implementing IEnumerable for the ancestry, or yielding the parents recursively. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

And as an alternative to Ander's solution, a non-recursive approach:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var obj = new object();
            int count = AllParents(obj).Count(); // Using Linq only here.
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<object> AllParents(object obj)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                obj = GetParentObject(obj);

                if (obj == null)
                    yield break;

                yield return obj;
            }
        }

        // This is merely a hacky test implementation.
        public static object GetParentObject(object obj)
        {
            if (--count == 0)
                return null;

            return obj;
        }

        private static int count = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function that can work on any type of object, with any object name containing the parent (uses `Func<T,T>`):

```
public static class MyExtensions {

  /// <summary>Gets an enumerable of all ancestors.</summary>
  public static IEnumerable<T> Ancestors<T>(this T obj, Func<T, T> expr) where T : class {
    obj = expr.Invoke(obj);
    while(obj != null) {
      yield return obj;
      obj = expr.Invoke(obj);
  }
}
```

Here's an example application that uses the function:

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass Parent { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    a.Parent = new MyClass();
    a.Parent.Parent = new MyClass();

    a.Ancestors(myObj => myObj.Parent).Count(); // Result: 2
}
```

Comment: There's no real point in creating a method *just* to do the count, if you're also going to have the method that computes the sequence, given that you can always call `Count` on it.  I'ts just not adding value.  This answer of course also has the same problem that the accepted answer has.  it's not actually using LINQ to solve this problem, it's just creating an iterator block.  LINQ and iterator blocks are two completely different things, even though one uses the other.

Comment: @Servy I originally had `AncestorCount` only, but in favor of `Ancestor().Count()`, I've removed it. Isn't LINQ just a way to query a dataset? This isn't an enumerable, but an object, so maybe that's the difference. I was mostly just putting this here as an improved version of the previous answers, so hopefully it will provide some value.

Comment: Yes, LINQ is a collection of functionality for querying data sets, but the question was very specific in what it was asking for, and none of the answers answer it.